# What does the "Persist state history" button do?

Tags: redux, redux-devtools-extension

What does this "Persist state history" button do in redux devtools? Why would the state not always be "persisted"?

[image: screenshot of redux devtools]

Comment: Persisted between page reloads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pin button UI code:

```js
{features.persist &&
  <Button
    Icon={PersistIcon}
    onClick={togglePersist}
  >Persist</Button>
}
```

See [v2.15.0/src/app/containers/App.js#L95](https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension/blob/v2.15.0/src/app/containers/App.js#L95)

`features` [doc](https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension/blob/v2.15.0/docs/API/Arguments.md#features):

```js
const composeEnhancers = composeWithDevTools({
  features: {
    pause: true, // start/pause recording of dispatched actions
    lock: true, // lock/unlock dispatching actions and side effects    
    persist: true, // persist states on page reloading
    export: true, // export history of actions in a file
    import: 'custom', // import history of actions from a file
    jump: true, // jump back and forth (time travelling)
    skip: true, // skip (cancel) actions
    reorder: true, // drag and drop actions in the history list 
    dispatch: true, // dispatch custom actions or action creators
    test: true // generate tests for the selected actions
  },
  // other options like actionSanitizer, stateSanitizer
});
```

`features.persist` means persist states on page reloading.